# Error after installing Redis on WSL: Executing test client: kill: No such process

Tags: redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Redis on WSL, but the cluster commands keep failing. I ran `make test` and got the following output:

```
...

[ok]: PSYNC2: cluster is consistent after failover

Logged warnings (pid 8970):
(none)

[exception]: Executing test client: kill: (9088): No such process.
kill: (9088): No such process
    while executing
"exec kill -9 $bench_pid"
    ("uplevel" body line 47)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug messages

    set no_exit 0                   ; # Do no..."
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {} {
start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug messages

    set no_exit 0          ..."
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {tags {"psync2"}} {
start_server {} {
start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug mess..."
    (file "tests/integration/psync2-reg.tcl" line 7)
    invoked from within
"source $path"
    (procedure "execute_tests" line 4)
    invoked from within
"execute_tests $data"
    (procedure "test_client_main" line 10)
    invoked from within
"test_client_main $::test_server_port "
Killing still running Redis server 7694
Killing still running Redis server 7702
Killing still running Redis server 7717
Killing still running Redis server 7721
Killing still running Redis server 7729
Killing still running Redis server 7735
Killing still running Redis server 7840
Killing still running Redis server 8107
Killing still running Redis server 8134
Killing still running Redis server 8136
Killing still running Redis server 8166
Killing still running Redis server 8640
Killing still running Redis server 8658
Killing still running Redis server 8701
Killing still running Redis server 8752
Killing still running Redis server 8907
Killing still running Redis server 8934
Killing still running Redis server 8969
Killing still running Redis server 9019
Killing still running Redis server 9061
Killing still running Redis server 9103
Killing still running Redis server 9146
Killing still running Redis server 9165
Killing still running Redis server 9203
Killing still running Redis server 9277
Killing still running Redis server 9286
I/O error reading reply
    while executing
"{*}$r type $k"
    (procedure "createComplexDataset" line 27)
    invoked from within
"createComplexDataset $r $ops"
    (procedure "bg_complex_data" line 4)
    invoked from within
"bg_complex_data [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1] [lindex $argv 2] [lindex $argv 3]"
    (file "tests/helpers/bg_complex_data.tcl" line 10)
I/O error reading reply
    while executing
"{*}$r type $k"
    (procedure "createComplexDataset" line 27)
    invoked from within
"createComplexDataset $r $ops"
    (procedure "bg_complex_data" line 4)
    invoked from within
"bg_complex_data [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1] [lindex $argv 2] [lindex $argv 3]"
    (file "tests/helpers/bg_complex_data.tcl" line 10)
I/O error reading reply
    while executing
"{*}$r type $k"
    (procedure "createComplexDataset" line 43)
    invoked from within
"createComplexDataset $r $ops"
    (procedure "bg_complex_data" line 4)
    invoked from within
"bg_complex_data [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1] [lindex $argv 2] [lindex $argv 3]"
    (file "tests/helpers/bg_complex_data.tcl" line 10)
Killing still running Redis server 9291
Killing still running Redis server 9303
Killing still running Redis server 9317
Makefile:262: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-stable/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

How do I fix this or what should be my next step in debugging this? I'm trying to install Redis 5.0.4. I don't have any firewalls enabled on WSL.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: No, got a mac instead

Comment: I got the same error running make test but I could still run the redis server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

after trying many times, i found the process that pid likes 9088 in "[exception]: Executing test client: kill: (9088): No such process."  is the redisbenchmark which become zombies process can't kill. that's the redis i installed by apt-get. 
so i remove the redisbenchmark in /usr/bin and remove redis i installed, and then make test successes.